# Update QMainWindow Parent elements from child

Tags: qt

I have two QMainWindows (A and B) defined, and B is initialized from A. In other words, B is the child of A.
I need to update the elements of A based on the user input in B, so what is the way to update elements in the parent window from child window because apparently we can't update elements across windows.

A simple example such as setting a label in A based on input in B would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Use signals and slots to do this, connect them before you instantiate either of the QMainWindows.

Usually I initialize all my windows from within my main class, so that I can set up the signals and slots.

//----- MORE INFO HERE ----//

When you create a new QWindow project, you get a mainwindow.cpp class, what you need to do is create a childWindow.cpp class which looks the same, then your main function looks like this:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    ChildWindow child;
    connect(&w, SIGNAL(labelChanged),
            &child, SLOT(updateLabelChange));
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Then, you can use signals and slots to control them. The important thing to remember is that you should write a new class for each window, so your child window should have its own class. Hope that helps.

Comment: I found a solution online as such, but i didn't know how to implement it. That is why i asked for a simple example if possible :)
Also, how can i connect them before i instantiate any of the classes especially that the parent window is the main one in the project.

Comment: @Ameen: Instantiate everything in the constructor and then make the connections at the end of the constructor.

Comment: There you go, I added a lot more information. Please +1 me if it helps you :)